# 14.04 Choppy Audio

Tags: sound

I've been following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) without any luck.  I'm on step 3, and [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=cf616b0fc3abfcc7aa5444981e86c71dc5a1eac6) was its output.  Can someone help me? Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I fixed it.  It was just clipping really bad, I noticed when it was just an advertisement or something it wouldn't do it, so I read up and ran alsamixer, put PCM at 50 and it solved it!

Comment: If this was the answer mark it as one

Comment: I will, but it won't let me mark my own answer as the answer for 3 days.

Comment: Ah. Sorry I often just fix grammatical issues :)